# Using Quaternion in libGDX

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx, quaternion

Can someone give me an explanation about how to use the `Quaternion` class in libGDX to move my camera around a sphere or just set it up, manipulate it, and apply it general? I am trying to acheive orbiting my camera around a sphere without gimbal lock, and I'm not having any luck getting the camera to do anything by using quaternions...

Comment: I created the `Quaternion` and initilized it to x=0, y=1, z=0, w=PI/2... but no matter what I change those values to and try to apply it to the camera, I'm not seeing any changes. I assume I'm supposed to set the view matrix to the matrix that is formed by the quaternion but it's not working and I'm not seeing how that will change my position around the sphere. I also don't know how to update the quaternion values dynamically to move it.

Comment: I can post some code in a few hours when I get out of work, if you would like to see that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up getting this to work. To apply a `Quaternion` to your camera just do this:

```
public void update(boolean updateFrustum)
{
    float aspect = camera.viewportWidth / camera.viewportHeight;
    camera.projection.setToProjection(Math.abs(camera.near), Math.abs(camera.far), camera.fieldOfView, aspect);
    camera.view.setToLookAt(camera.position, tmp.set(camera.position).add(camera.direction), camera.up);

    // This is all you need to do!
    // the rotate() method takes in a Quaternion
    // It needs to be after the call to setToLookAt()
    camera.view.rotate(rotation);

    camera.combined.set(camera.projection);
    Matrix4.mul(camera.combined.val, camera.view.val);

    if (updateFrustum)
    {
        camera.invProjectionView.set(camera.combined);
        Matrix4.inv(camera.invProjectionView.val);
        camera.frustum.update(camera.invProjectionView);
    }
}
```

This is exactly the same as the update() method in the `PerspectiveCamera` class except for the part about adding the rotation quaternion.